# Scheme several actions if an if-statement proves true

Tags: if-statement, syntax, scheme

The way I understand a scheme if-statement is that the first condition is when the if-statement is true, and the second statement is when it is false. What if I want several conditions for when the statement proves true?

An example:

```
(if (= a b)
    (set! ([a 2]))  // This shall happen when true
    (set! ([b 4]))  // This shall happen when true

    (set! ([a b])) // This shall happen when NOT true
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a possibility of multiple statements inside a conditional statement's body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263359/is-there-a-possibility-of-multiple-statements-inside-a-conditional-statements-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use begin in an if statement. like so:

```
(if (something)
(begin (foo)
       (bar)))
```

Comment: @Avenon You could also use `cond`: as in `(cond [something (foo) (bar)])`